# String output formatting

Tags: python, string

My Code:

```
infile = open("table1.txt", "r")
a_list = infile.read().split("\n")
infile.close()

for pass_num in range(len(a_list)-1, 0, -1):

    for i in range(0, pass_num):

        if int(a_list[i].split(",")[1].strip()) > int(a_list[i+1].split(",")[1].strip()):
        a_list[i], a_list[i+1] = a_list[i+1], a_list[i]


        if (int(a_list[i].split(",")[1].strip()) == int(a_list[i+1].split(",")[1].strip())) and ((int(a_list[i].split(",")[2]) - int(a_list[i].split(",")[3].strip())) > (int(a_list[i+1].split(",")[2].strip()) - int(a_list[i+1].split(",")[3].strip()))):
        a_list[i], a_list[i+1] = a_list[i+1], a_list[i]


        if (int(a_list[i].split(",")[1].strip()) == int(a_list[i+1].split(",")[1].strip())) and ((int(a_list[i].split(",")[2]) - int(a_list[i].split(",")[3].strip())) == (int(a_list[i+1].split(",")[2].strip()) - int(a_list[i+1].split(",")[3].strip()))):
            if (int(a_list[i].split(",")[2])) > int(a_list[i+1].split(",")[2]):
                a_list[i], a_list[i+1] = a_list[i+1], a_list[i]

a_list.reverse()

print("    Team" + " "*(30-len("    Team")) + "Points" + " "*2 + "Diff" + " "*4 + "Goals")

for i in range(len(a_list)):

    team = a_list[i].split(",")[0]
    points = a_list[i].split(",")[1]
    goalfor = int(a_list[i].split(",")[2].strip())
    goalagainst = int(a_list[i].split(",")[3].strip())
    diff = goalfor - goalagainst

print(str(i+1).rjust(2) + ". " + '{0:27} {1:4} {2:4} {3:5} : {4:2}'.format(team, points, diff, goalfor, goalagainst)) 
#Area of interest above^
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Would anyone know how to edit the area of interest in the commented piece of code to produce the desired output with the `9's lined up underneath the 3 in 13? Ive been trying .rjust(1)` but it wont seem to work.

Comment: Try using tabs instead of spaces I think they even out. \t

Comment: So what exactly is the code?

Comment: Instead of print("    Team") print("\tTeam")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python string format support [align](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

> align   ::=  "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"
>
> '<'    Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space (this is the default for most objects).
>
> '>'    Forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space (this is the default for numbers).
>
> '='    Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any) but before the digits. This is used for printing fields in the form ‘+000000120’. This alignment option is only valid for numeric types.
>
> '^'    Forces the field to be centered within the available space.

So  use `{:>}` for right align.

**DEMO**

```
>>> print "{}\t{:<2}".format(1, 20) 
1   20
>>> print "{}\t{:<2}".format(1, 2)
1   2 
>>> print "{}\t{:>2}".format(1, 2)
1    2
>>> print "{}\t{:>2}".format(1, 20)
1   20
```

In your case, just align the format in the following way:

```
print(str(1).rjust(2) + ". " + '{0:27} {1:>4} {2:4} {3:5} : {4:2}'.format("adasd", 1, -12, 1, 2))
                                        ^^^
```